# Copying directories and incrementing name

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder "named training01". I Want to run a script that copies the directory and its contents 12 times so I have "training01, training02, ..., training13". It must be really simple but I'm noob to bash scripts. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

org="training01"
base=$(echo "$org" | sed -e 's/[0-9]//g')
for ((i=2; i<=13; i++)); do
    dest=$(printf "%s%02d" "$base" $i)
    cp -a "$org" "$dest"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=2

    while [ $i -le 13 ]
     do
      if [i -le 9]; then
       cp training01 "training0$i"
      else
       cp training01 "training$i"
      fi

     i=`expr $i+1`
     done
```

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was this:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 1 13)
  do
    cp -r "../path/to/file" "target/directory/training$i"
  done
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed :)